# Java Swing Gridlayout VERTICAL constraint

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, gaps-in-visuals

Is it possible to add components in a Gridlayout verticaly ? I mean the next one above the previous one ?

Thank you

Comment: You should accept more answers. You've asked 55 questions yet accepted answers on less than half of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no layout that allows you to stack vertically from the bottom up, at least that I'm aware of.  If you want vertical stacking you can either use a `GridLayout` with a single column or a `BoxLayout` with a vertical axis.  By nesting panels and combining layouts you should easily get what you need, e.g. panels with a vertical layout all laid out in a horizontal container.

Comment: Good use case for a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or  [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Layouts like BoxLayout and GridLayout display components from top to bottom when you use:

```
panel.add( someComponent );
```

but you can always use:

```
panel.add(someComponent, 0);
```

to insert components at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Though this answer is not related to *Grid layout*, i would highly recommend using JGoodies forms layout. Its highly flexible. http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/index.html

```
                          /* 1                    2      3       4    5                   6     7      8       9*/      
            String col1 = "left:max(20dlu;pref), 3dlu, 70dlu, 15dlu,left:max(10dlu;pref),10dlu, 70dlu, 70dlu, 70dlu";
                          /* 1   2     3   4  5   6    7   8    */
            String row1 = "  p, 5dlu, p, 3dlu, p, 5dlu, p, 9dlu, ";
            FormLayout layout = new FormLayout( col1, row1 + row2 + row3 + row4 + row5 + row6);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout); 
             panel.setBorder(Borders.DIALOG_BORDER);

            // Fill the table with labels and components.
            CellConstraints cc = new CellConstraints();
            panel.add(createSeparator("Registration Information"), cc.xyw(1, 1, 7));
            panel.add(new JLabel("Patient ID"), cc.xy(1, 3));
            panel.add(pid, cc.xyw(3, 3, 1));
            panel.add(new JLabel("Date and Time"), cc.xy(5, 3));
```

You can hand code to plot each component any where in the defined layout designed ie wrt to col and rows. **Even vertical arrangement.** 
Read whitepaper: http://www.jgoodies.com/articles/forms.pdf